# The contract of an MP

Tags: united-kingdom

The [Parliamentary Oath](https://www.parliament.uk/about/how/elections-and-voting/swearingin/) is taken by all MPs.

Are any other oaths taken by MPs?

Is there a written contract that they must sign: for example to commit to represent their constituents?

Comment: Can we keep Brexit out of this please?

Comment: @Ben Why? It's a good example of the complication of trying to measure what "representing their constituents" would be.

Comment: Even if such a contract existed, wouldn't it be meaningless? How would it be enforced? The judiciary is a separate power from the legislative; they wouldn't want to get involved in such matters.

Comment: FWIW, not all MPs take an oath – many take an affirmation instead. I know that (the title of) the linked page glosses over this, but the distinction is important to some people (me included).

Comment: @Abigail indeed.  Furthermore, who would be the other party to the contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ahead of the 2010 election, Parliament published a [New Members' Guidebook](https://www.parliament.uk/documents/foi/new-members-guide-2010.pdf) which aims to give new MPs an idea of what would be required of them.  The only thing that it says is legally required of all MPs, before they can take their seat or draw a salary, is the oath or affirmation that is taken at the start of each Parliament.

There are other items that new MPs must address when they enter Parliament.  The one thing that is likely applicable to most (if not all) members, is that they employ any staff that they may require in both their Westminster and constituency offices, so they will need to sign relevant employment contracts with those members of staff.

Also, members are required, where applicable, to register any potential outside interests on the Register of Members’ Financial Interests within a month of taking their seats.